# How to use two LEFT JOINs on one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have two queries, but I want the results to be in the same return table.

The first query returns a list of all posts with their comments as a list. The comments are stored in a different table.

```
SELECT E.id, E.time, E.title, E.body, E.type, C.comments
FROM elements E
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT elementID, GROUP_CONCAT(body SEPARATOR '|-|') AS comments
    FROM comments
    GROUP BY elementID
) C on C.elementID = E.id
```

The second query returns a list of all posts with a count of how many likes/upvotes the post has as a new column. The likes are stored in a different table.

```
SELECT E.id, E.googleID, E.title, L.likeCount
FROM elements E
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT elementID, COUNT(id) AS likeCount
    FROM likes
    GROUP BY elementID
) L ON L.elementID = E.id;
```

How would I have a concatenated list of comments as a column, and number of likes as a column, in the same query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, why can't you `JOIN` both the query like you have already done for other query

```
SELECT E.id, E.time, E.title, E.body, E.type, C.comments, E.googleID, L.likeCount
FROM elements E
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT elementID, GROUP_CONCAT(body SEPARATOR '|-|') AS comments
    FROM comments
    GROUP BY elementID
) C on C.elementID = E.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT elementID, COUNT(id) AS likeCount
    FROM likes
    GROUP BY elementID
) L ON L.elementID = E.id;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can "stack" joins of the same level together, like this:

```
SELECT
    E.id
,   E.time
,   E.title
,   E.googleID
,   E.body
,   E.type
,   C.comments
,   L.likeCount
FROM elements E
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT elementID, GROUP_CONCAT(body SEPARATOR '|-|') AS comments
    FROM comments
    GROUP BY elementID
) C on C.elementID = E.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT elementID, COUNT(id) AS likeCount
    FROM likes
    GROUP BY elementID
) L ON L.elementID = E.id;
```

Simply put a set of columns you wanted to return from both joins into the select list, and put the joins next to each other.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT E.id, E.time, E.title, E.body, E.type,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(body SEPARATOR '|-|') AS comments
FROM comment c where C.elementID= E.id group by C.elementID) as comments,
(SELECT  COUNT(id)
FROM likes L where L.elementID=E.id
GROUP BY elementID) as likeCount
FROM elements E
```

Comment: It says there is a syntax error near "comments C on E.id=C.elementID LEFT likes L on E.id=L.elementID group by E.id" at line 5.

Comment: @Connorelsea : I updated it. Please check and let me know.

Comment: Thank you. I really like your answer. Not only does it shorten the query a lot, but it also solves the problem of 0 likes returning as null, which I was having to correct in my server code. Thanks!

Comment: welcome...I am glad it worked for you as per your complete requirement.  :)

Comment: As a note to anyone reading this:  this is incorrect, both in the calculation of `likeCount` and in duplicating comments.  Other other two answers are correct.

Comment: This is returning double the amount of likes in the table. How do I fix this?